# Post Data in Django Value error

Tags: python, django

I'm new in the Django.I have 2 models, one of them Post,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit',on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, blank = True)
```

and next is Unit model,

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique = True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I use ForeignKey, and i have such problem. In my site I use Unit model like drop down list

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_unit">Unit</label>
    <select  class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name="unit">
        {%for unit in units%}
            <option>{{ unit.name }}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
</div>
```

and when I try to create a new Post by site I have a value error **"Cannot assign "'Moscow'": "Post.unit" must be a "Unit" instance."**

This is my function in the view.py, that create.

```
def post_new(request):
posts = Post.objects.all()
units = Unit.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    title  = request.POST['title']
    text   = request.POST['text']
    unit   = request.POST['unit']
    user   = User.objects.first()
    status = StatusOfPost.objects.first()

    post = Post.objects.create(
        author = user,
        title  = title,
        text   = text,
        unit   = unit,
        status = status
    )
    return redirect('postsList')

return render(request, 'post_new.html', {'posts': posts, 'units': units})
```

What I must do, i don't understand. How apply Unit.name value to Post.unit.
Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, `request.POST['unit']` is not a `Unit` object but a name, you need to query the `Unit` object.

So replace:

```
unit = request.POST['unit']
```

by:

```
unit = Unit.objects.get(name=request.POST['unit'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me!